# How to include jQuery in a WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new to WordPress and I am figuring out how to include jQuery into a theme.

I create the following function into **functions.php** theme:

```
function load_java_scripts() {
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript that handle the SlideShow:
    wp_enqueue_script('jQuery-js', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js', array(), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

So I think that I can add it as some other JavaScript or CSS local resources but I am not sure about this method because in this case the **jquery.js** is not a local resource but is an online resource (is it the same thing?)

I also have some doubts because searching online I have found different methods to add jQuery to my theme, like this [one](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/).

Can you give me some information about how to correctly complete this task?

Comment: Why are you including jquery manualy? Isn't it allready included?

Answer (score 8):

Is there any specific reason why you're not using the jQuery found in WordPress?

If you need to add your JavaScript file which depends on jQuery, you can add jQuery as a [dependency](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery).

```
<?php

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', #your JS file
        array( 'jquery' ) #dependencies
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
```

Note that WordPress loads jQuery in [no conflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). so your code should be like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Comment: Thanks @RRikesh, that was the issue. I'd overlooked the jQuery loading. I wasn't aware of the no conflict wrappers. I can't seem to mark your answer as the solution for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

Since WP already comes with jQuery, I would simply load it for your theme, add it like this into your functions.php

```
function load_scripts(){
    //Load scripts:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); # Loading the WordPress bundled jQuery version.
    //may add more scripts to load like jquery-ui
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

There are several ways to include jQuery into a theme. I always use WP bundled version which I find very simple.

Answer (score 4):

In wordpress No need for Custom Jquery.
Add dependencies as 'jquery' it'll automatically get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?php
    function load_external_jQuery() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery 
        $url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'; // the URL to check against  
        $test_url = @fopen($url,'r'); // test parameters  
        if( $test_url !== false ) { // test if the URL exists if exists then register the external file  
            wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');
        }
        else{// register the local file 
            wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js', __FILE__, false, '1.7.2', true);  
        }
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // enqueue the jquery here
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_local_jQuery'); // initiate the function 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods below to include jQuery:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );  

wp_enqueue_script( 'load-js-validate', 'foldername/jquery.js' );

Directly add in header file.<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>

function js_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_scripts' ); // add this in function file
```