# Console Log after submit shows Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function for my Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit my search word, but ajax returned

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

I use custom script defined here:

> wp_enqueue_script( 'script.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
>   '/assets/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.1');

In my header I call this scripts:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

my form on home page:

```
  <form method="" id="submitSearch" action="/">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

in My JS :

```
$ = jQuery;

 $('#submitSearch').submit(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        let data = new FormData();

        console.log("GG");

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
```

What exactly did I wrong, please?

Comment: Ok, I understand, so what kind of version should I use? and my script.js? what kind of version to set? Or should I just call my script.js in head?

Comment: and should I call script.js not from the functions.php, but in head, through <script></script>

Comment: You are loading 3 versions of jQuery, and 2 versions of Bootstrap! They will conflict with each other and cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: ok, so can you reccommend me, what javascript remove?

Comment: @Ouroborus no, the recommended way of calling your own scripts is with `wp_enqueue_script()`, and it is well documented, [here's a random example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21258129/6089612).

Comment: Delete all your jQuery references in your header, and see the answer I linked to above - just enqueue your `script.js` and specify jQuery is a dependency.

Comment: Dude, what are you doing? You have 3 versions of jQuery and 2 versions of bootstrap.  You need to stop what you are doing and go and do a basic tutorial first so you have some type of understanding of what you are actualy doing, becauase you simply don't know what you are doing right now.

Comment: @Don`t Panic thanks for the advice,  I enqueue custom script in functions.php with jquery dependecny and remove all <script> from the head. but problem does not solve

Comment: What about `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: @AlonEitan it is weird you know, cause other functions are submitted with $.ajax. but only one I now programmed does not work.. Still I have a lot of errors in console.log,  but it's on the right track, I believe it. Anyway, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery in no conflict mode:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#submitSearch').submit(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        let data = new FormData();

        console.log("GG");

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Source https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ and https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Then in your functions.php call your custom script.

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/my-custom-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

You normally do not need to call jQuery again because wordpress already loads it.

If however you need to use a specific version of jQuery, you should remove the default jQuery first then load your version

```
// include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
    // replace the above url with the version of jQuery you want.
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

Source https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Hope this clears things up.  :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, so stupid problem from my side. I had called some scripts in bottom part of my home page... but your code looks really nice. Definitely will implement it in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `($ = jQuery)` in your script

Comment: I tried that, but it did not change anything, probably problem will be above, too much scripts called